# Which type of OpenAPI pattern format is valid?

Tags: openapi

Currently looking at an `openapi.yaml` that has two different formats for the `pattern` validator for a string.

```yaml
    Country:
      pattern: ^(A(D|E|F|G|I|L|M|N|O|R|S|T|Q|U|W|X|Z)|B(A|B|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|L|M|N|O|R|S|T|V|W|Y|Z))$
      type: string
    Currency:
      pattern: /^AED|AFN|ALL|AMD$/
      type: string
```

The documentation doesn't show `/` as a boundary character at all, so is this valid or invalid?

I've used the Swagger Editor to input both but neither gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format for the `pattern` is `myregex` (formatted as a YAML or JSON string, with proper escaping if needed), not `/myregex/` or `/myregex/flags`.

Source: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1985

Examples of valid patterns:

```yaml
# YAML
pattern: \d+      # not anchored
pattern: ^\d+$    # anchored

pattern: '\d+'    # \d+
pattern: "\\d+"   # \d+

# JSON
"pattern": "\\d+"     # \d+
"pattern": "^\\d+$"   # ^\d+$
```

In your example, the Country pattern is correct, and the Currency pattern is incorrect.

In case of `pattern: /^AED|AFN|ALL|AMD$/` (which is equivalent to `pattern: "/^AED|AFN|ALL|AMD$/"`), the `/` is considered a part of the pattern string itself, not the boundary character. As a result, this pattern won't match anything because extra characters appear outside of `^...$`.